# I click on one object, while in vertex paint, it shows it's colors, but it will not show any other objects colors

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-colors

I'm new to blender.

I click on one object, while in vertex paint, it shows it's colors, but it will not show any other objects colors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OH, forgot to add. I've tried to scrounge around for ways to fix this, and everything is awfully vague or doesn't help me much. So, suggest as much as you can guys, thanks.

Comment: How do I show all the colors at once this hurts my brain

Comment: My bad, you can activate the Attribute option in the Viewport Shading panel, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Viewport Shading* panel, enable the *Attribute* option:

[image]